# Rails 3.2.2 sometime session automatically clear in the next action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on the Rails 3.2.2 application. I am setting the session variables in the submit action of the form and after that using ajax action rendering another form on the same page. I set the session variables like

```
session[:obj_id] = 23
```

But When I submit the second form and tried to access the session[:obj_id] variable, then I found it nil

How is it ?

Am I missing something important.?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting something similar.